# Difference __init__.py functionality between version 12 and below

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have been working with Odoo since v10, on every custom module I use **init**.py to import the models and controllers folder as python manual says.

```
from . import models
from . import controllers
```

In v12 is not reading from inside the folders saying that can't find the model, but if I move the files into the root module folder and import the files it works!

**init**.py 
root module folder

```
from . import models
from . import controllers
```

**init**.py models folder

```
from . import mymodel
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't Odoo load the modules or is your IDE telling you, that there is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is related with python Versions. Since Odoo 10 users python 2 and from Odoo version 11 onwards python3 is used.

In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer available - only absolute imports and explicit relative imports are supported. In addition, star imports (e.g. from x import *) are only permitted in module level code. So here In Odoo you have to import model like this.

`from odoo import api, fields, models, _`

Answer (score 1):

Odoo version 12: Example addon folder is called addon1. This Addon1 sits inside addon folder as normal.

Inside addon1 folder:
Your init file has to be renamed to double underscore
eg

```
__init__.py
```

This you import as you mentioned (note that coding: utf-8 line in first line)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from . import controllers
from . import models
```

Inside your addon1 folder, has a folder called models (as you mentioned).
Inside models folder, has your init file, this has to be renamed to double underscore
eg

```
__init__.py
```

In that file, you import your python files that's inside your models folder (first line has that coding line)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from . import models
from . import mymodel
```

[so your mymodel.py file is inside your models folder, which is the file you created]

Inside your models folder, your python file models.py (eg mymodel.py) you need to import like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api
```

Extra info below regarding odoo 12 security feature:
odoo 12 has the new security folder called folder security, file inside it is
ir.model.acces.csv - you'll need to add your model into the security if you want to see it if it's a new menu 
eg

```
access_classname_unique,addon1.addon1,model_classname,,1,1,1,1
```

the model_classname: If your class name is _name = "mymodel.category" (replace . with _) then will become model_mymodel.category
eg

```
access_mymodel_category,addon1.addon1,model_classname,,1,1,1,1
```